# Overwrite of the save method to ensure integrity in database doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models

A user always has one default dashboard for each company they are associated with. They can add new dashboards, as soon as they set one as the default, the other one gets reset. To achieve this I tried overwriting the save method on the Dashboard model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_default:
        for dash in Dashboard.objects.filter(user=self.user, company=self.company):
            if dash.is_default:
                dash.is_default = False
                dash.save()
    else:
        if Dashboard.objects.filter(user=self.user, company=self.company, is_default=True).exclude(id=self.id).count() == 1:
            raise ValidationError(
                'There has to be a default dashboard per company for this user.')
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The code above doesn't work, as it lets me set a dashboard with is_default=False and doesn't raise the ValidationError, if the criteria isn't fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this change:

```py
...
if not Dashboard.objects.filter(user=self.user, company=self.company, is_default=True).exclude(id=self.id).exists():
    raise ValidationError()
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my start-up script stopped working, so I am debugging that, but it seems like a problem during the creation of the dashboards.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. If you are interested: Another improvement could be to remove all existing defaults with one query like this: `Dashboard.objects.filter(user=self.user, company=self.company, is_default=True).update(is_default=False)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually already did that since that since I posted this!